# Single-table design or multi-table for unrelated entities?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am new to DynamoDB though I am not totally new to NoSQL paradigm. I worked with Firebase years ago.

I spent the last couple days learning and studying most of the materials that I can find on the Internet about single-table design, a design approach advocated by the DynamoDB team. I think I have got the essence of it and am fascinated by the concept.

All the materials that I read on single-table design are under the context of related entities, however. This makes me wonder what about unrelated entities (as in I don't need to perform JOINs on the entities if I were to implement the service with a SQL database). What are the pros and cons of putting unrelated entities in the same table vs putting them in separate tables? (in terms of performance, monetary cost, maintainability and etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some cost benefit to storing unrelated entities in the same table.

But only if using provision capacity, and really only then if the I/O to the unrelated data is insignificant in terms of the I/O to the main table.

So if you could have 1 table with 35 RCU/WCU vs having that table plus another table with 1 RCU/WCU, you could save a few pennies on capacity.  Storage cost would be the same regardless.

But don't forget that the DDB "always free" tier includes 25GB of storage, 25 WCU, 25 RCU. Number of tables isn't a factor.

At scale, it'd be better to have them separate so you could better tune the capacity to the workload.

I suppose if you needed a million 1 xCU tables rather than 1 25 xCU table.... it'd make a difference.  But pay-per-request is likely a better option in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Aside from the flexibility of tuning the capacity to the workload like you mentioned, I think keeping separate tables in this case also requires less documentation as unnecessary index overloading can be avoided and thus key attrs can have more meaningful names.

Comment: Does DynamoDB supports reads/writes in parallel in the context of separate tables? What about separate partitions?

Comment: Yes, the BatchWriteItem and BatchGetItem operate in parallel regardless of table/partition.